# Handle Undefined Offset warning in PHP, when value at the index is an object

Tags: php

I have a code like this:

```
class PlayerList{
    public static $player_list= array();
    //other functions
    function getPlayer($playerNumber){

           if(isset((self::$player_list[$playerNumber])))
              return self::$player_list[$playerNumber];
            else
              return NULL;
      }
```

This function `getPlayer($playerNumber)` should return the player object in the static array `$player_list`  indexed using the given `$playerNumber`. It works when the index exists else throws an undefined offset. The index is an important attribute of objects of Player class, so re-ordering the array is out of question.

Now, in the calling part:

```
$players=new PlayerList();
$playerNumber=readline("\n\nEnter player number:");
$player=$players->getPlayer($playerNumber); 

if(//valid player){
//code
}
else{
//code
}
```

How do i check if the indexed player exists or not,and if not, return null, in the `getPlayer` function itself, and prevent PHP from giving undefined offset notice?

Comment: Where does it throw the error message, show the error and the line number that is reporting the error

Comment: @RiggsFolly not an error but a notice, in cases when the index doesn't exist.  return `self::$player_list[$playerNumber]` is the one showed, but vanishes when i over ride the notices in line `$player=$players->getPlayer($playerNumber);` with a "@" at its start, i.e. `@ $player=$players->getPlayer($playerNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning NULL when you cannot find a player, simply test for NULL using `isset()`

```
$player=$players->getPlayer($playerNumber); 
if ( isset($player) ) { 
    // Player exists
}else{
    // Player Does NOT exists
}
```

In fact you could probably get away with a simple

```
$player=$players->getPlayer($playerNumber); 
if ( $player ) { 
    // Player exists
}else{
    // Player Does NOT exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you have a typo in your code assuming a variable called `$playereNumber`. If this is not the issue, you can try following code for your class.

```
class PlayerList
{
    public static $playerList = [];


    function getPlayer($index)
    {
        return isset(static::$playerList[$index]) ? static::$playerList[$index] : null;
    }
}
```

You should also consider not making the `$playerList` static in case you will be loading them from some database later.

Comment: Thats basically what he is doing already, all you have done is polish it a little

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
class PlayerList
{
    public static $playerList = [];


    function getPlayer($index)
    {
        return isset(static::$playerList[$index]) ? static::$playerList[$index] : null;
    }
}
$players=new PlayerList();
$playerNumber=readline("\n\nEnter player number:");
$player=$players->getPlayer($playerNumber); 

if($player){
//player exist
}
else{
//player is null
}
```